# Border of a binary mask

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a binary mask and I want the borders of this mask to be labeled with a value, e.g value 2. It would be preferable, the border width to be of a specific percentage. In other words, it would be perfect, if we could change the border mask dynamically. Could anyone please help me do it in an efficient, quick way?

Thank you very much, your help is highly appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be less of an answer and more of a guiding comment. Tools that you could use - IMDILATE (for changing the width of the boundary) and BWMORPH (for calculating the change in width, for which their skeletonization option could be explored), to be used on the binary image that denotes the boundary pixels. That's all I could think of, off the top of my head.

Comment: I performed image closure and then I subtract the masks. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the Image Processing Toolbox, an easy way to do this is with `bwperim` or `bwboundaries`.

Example of `bwperim`:

```
BW1 = imread('circbw.tif');
BW2 = bwperim(BW1,8);
figure; subplot(121);imshow(BW1);subplot(122);imshow(BW2)
```

[image]

However, to change the border width, you would have to combine the two images (`BW3 = BW1 | BW2;`) and rerun `bwperim` (`BW4 = bwperim(BW3,8);`). So, for anything more than a single pixel width boundary, I'd use `imdilate` and `xor` the masks:

```
BW1 = imread('circbw.tif');
BW2 = imdilate(BW1,strel('disk',2));
BW_border = xor(BW2,BW1);
```

[image]